# How to use AppleTalk to transfer files between iPhone and Mac wirelessly?

Tags: macos, iphone, file-sharing

I've used scp and ftp to get files in and out of my iPhone. But they are kinda awkward and un-Mac. I was thinking whether it's possible to share out my iPhone using maybe something like AppleTalk, like how I share files with other Macs. Any ideas? Has anybody tried it before. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming this is jailbroken? If so, please specify.

Comment: It's using scp, already jailbroken.

Answer (score 3):

You cant' do this out of the box without jailbreaking your iPhone an intalling Cydia.

But since you can already use scp, I assume your iPhone must already be jailbroken. ;-)

Alright, if you’re using Mac OS 10.5 (Leopard), life is easy: the connection between your iPhone and Mac is seamless.

Lauch Cydia and install the Netatalk package, which is actually an open source impementation of AppleTalk.

> Tap **Sections**. The **Netatalk** package should be under the **Network** section. *Install it.*

[image: CyDIA]

Once you have installed Netatalk, connecting to your iPhone is a breeze:

1. Make sure your iPhone has **Wifi is
   turned on.**
2. Your iPhone should show up in the Finder as shared
   device.
3. Next, click **Connect As** button to
   logon as another user. You'll be ased to enter the username/password.
4. Type **root** or **mobile** for name and
   **alpine** for password.
   Then click “Connect”.

*Now your iPhone is connected with your Mac.* You should see a “mobile” folder and you can drag & drop files into the iPhone. This is great for Cycorder users.

Answer (score 1):

Keep using SSH, especially if you use RSA/DSA keys to login and not passwords.
If you want it to integrate with the Finder then use a program like [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac).
It should show up like a regular volume, and you should be able to use it in every app.

Comment: +1 for ExpanDrive. It allows you to mount any directory on any machine you have SSH access to as a volume.  Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.modmyi.com/wiki/index.php/AFP_iPhone_from_Finder) (with screenshots) about setting up AFP.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the iPhone as a Data Storage (and viewer for native known file formats like pdf, doc etc.) you could use sth. like AirSharing (http://avatron.com/apps/).
I think you can find a bunch of similar Apps, too.
AirSharing uses the WebDav protocol for file exchange.

I don't think AppleTalk is more Mac-like or has any advantage over most other protocols in this use case.